# VBA: Access to Powerpoint.Application Object throws automation error

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have two macros. One in a PowerPoint presentation and one in an Excel workbook.
The one in the Powerpoint presentation looks as follows:

```
Sub UpdateCores(ByRef WorkbookPaths() As Variant)

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Call GetWorkbookPathVariables
        
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    xlApp.Workbooks.Open (SourceWorkbookFullPath)
    
    Call xlApp.Run("RemoteUpdateManager", WorkbookPaths, ActivePresentation.Application)

End Sub
```

And this is the macro `RemoteUpdateManager` in the Excel file:

```
Sub RemoteUpdateManager(ByRef WorkbookPath() As Variant, pptApp As PowerPoint.Application)

    Call GetWorkbookPathVariables ' Pfäde für Sparten
    Dim LinkedWorkbook As Object
    Dim LinkedWorkbookFullPath As Variant
    Dim OpenedInstances As New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    For Each LinkedWorkbookFullPath In WorkbookPath

        Call UpdateLinkedWorkbook(CStr(LinkedWorkbookFullPath), OpenedInstances)
        
    Next LinkedWorkbookFullPath

    Call pptApp.Run("UpdateSlides", OpenedInstances) ' <-- Automation error occurs here
    
    Set OpenedInstances = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

The problem i have is that if i restart my pc and all cashes are cleaned this automation error occurs with
the extra line that the system call failed in this line: `Call pptApp.Run("UpdateSlides", OpenedInstances)`

It's very hard to reproduce this error. Even deleting the OfficeFileCache won't fix it.

To clarify, after the first time the error occurs the macro runs fine without any issues. That's why assume it has to do with accessing the cache.

UPDATE: I've figured out that it doesn't have to do with the Application.Run function. Apparently the Powerpoint.Application object `pptApp` is not accessible and that it it's a registration issue and that Powerpoint has to be re-registered in the COM.